# How to execute Oracle Stored Procedure from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

**when I try to run the command:**

$pdo = DB::connection($group)->select("exec prc_recebcobdsg('0', 'null','01-01-2021', '27-01-2021', 'null')");

**My Laravel page returns:**
Error Code : 900
Error Message : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Position : 0
Statement : exec prc_recebcobdsg('0', 'null','01-01-2021', '27-01-2021', 'null')
Bindings : []
(SQL: exec prc_recebcobdsg('0', 'null','01-01-2021', '27-01-2021', 'null'))

**Where am I wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Laravel but I believe there are two issues.
Firstly `exec` is not actually an Oracle statement it is just a shorthand available in sqlplus and sqldeveloper and other clients. Usually you need to enclose the procedure call in a begin / end block.
The second issue is that execution of a stored procedure is not really a select so you can not use the `select` method of connection. I believe you can use `exec` method.
Something like this should work:

```
DB::connection($group)->getPdo()->exec("begin prc_recebcobdsg('0', 'null','01-01-2021', '27-01-2021', 'null'); end;");
```

Comment: @gustavo don't forget to use "bind parameters" instead of hardcoding the constants such as your data values.  Binding is important for security and scalability.